# Filter Outlook emails based on Subject then download attachments

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I am trying to do the following:

1. Search for unread emails
2. Open the ones with specific keywords
3. Download attachments from the email (would be nice if I could also filter through attachments too)
4. Mark email as read.

This is what I am working with.

```
Sub DownloadAttachmentFirstUnreadEmail()
    Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
    Dim oOlItm As Object, oOlAtch As Object
    Dim strFilter As String

    '~~> New File Name for the attachment
    Dim NewFileName As String
    NewFileName = AttachmentPath & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & "-"

    '~~> Get Outlook instance
    Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
    Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    '~~> Check if there are any actual unread emails
    If oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True").count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "NO Unread Email In Inbox"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '~~> Extract the attachment from the 1st unread email
    For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")

        'The above loop begins to read everything that is unread.

        'This is the part that gets tricky
        'Here we need to begin filtering subject headline
        'The line below defines what we are filtering

        strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%sketch%'"

        If filteredItems.count = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "No emails found"
            Found = False
        Else

            '~~> Check if the email actually has an attachment
            If oOlItm.Attachments.count <> 0 Then
                For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments
                    '~~> Download the attachment
                    oOlAtch.SaveAsFile NewFileName & oOlAtch.FileName
                    Exit For
                Next
            Else
                MsgBox "The First item doesn't have an attachment"
            End If

        End If

       '~~> Mark 1st unread email as read
        oOlItm.UnRead = False
        DoEvents
        oOlItm.Save
        Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The strFilter that you define is only a string...it does not actually filter your mails result....but by the way, you post your code but not the issue you have with... difficult to guess....

Comment: What's the question here?  Is there an issue with your code? Something missing from your code?

Comment: I'm still working on it, my problem is getting the filter to work.

Answer (score 0):

With the way your code is structured it would likely work if you were using Instr on each unread item in the first filter.

A second filter is more efficient.

```
Sub FilerBySubjectUnreadEmail()

    Dim oOlAp As Object
    Dim oOlns As Object
    Dim oOlInb As Object

    Dim oOlItm As Object
    Dim oOlAtch As Object
    Dim strFilter As String

    Dim objUnreadItems As Items
    Dim filteredItems As Items
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Get Outlook instance
    On Error Resume Next ' You can use this as there is a purpose
    Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
    On Error GoTo 0  ' One line from On Error Resume Next. If say five or more lines you are fired.

    If oOlAp Is Nothing Then Set oOlAp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

    Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set objUnreadItems = oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")

    '~~> Check if there are unread emails
    If objUnreadItems.count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "NO Unread Email In Inbox"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Change sketch to what you are looking for
    strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%sketch%'"

    Set filteredItems = objUnreadItems.Restrict(strFilter)

    If filteredItems.count = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No emails found with applicable subject"
        Exit Sub

    Else

        For i = filteredItems.count To 1 Step -1

            'Debug.Print i & " - " & filteredItems.count

            '~~> Check if the email actually has an attachment
            Set oOlItm = filteredItems(i)

            If oOlItm.Attachments.count <> 0 Then
                For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments
                    Debug.Print oOlItm.Subject
                    Debug.Print oOlAtch.DisplayName
                Next

                '~~> Mark email as read
                filteredItems(i).UnRead = False
                DoEvents

                ' Safest to save the item
                '  in case it is needed
                '  but not necessary with Read/Unread
                ' oOlItm.Save

        Else
            MsgBox oOlItm.Subject & " doesn't have an attachment."

        End If

    Next

    End If

ExitRoutine:
    Set oOlAp = Nothing
    Set oOlns = Nothing
    Set oOlInb = Nothing

    Set oOlItm = Nothing
    Set oOlAtch = Nothing

    Set objUnreadItems = Nothing
    Set filteredItems = Nothing

End Sub
```